# 'j' doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group issue in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am running into an error when using `data.table`. The error message is:

> Error in `[.data.table(x.out, , if (all(V3 > 25)) c(as.character(V1[1])`,  : 
>     `j` doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group

I'd like to know how to get around this error.

My data looks like this (see at the bottom of this post for a reproducible form of the data using `dput`):

```
c007d.1    1       2
c007d.1    2       2
c007d.1    3       2
c007d.1    4       31
c007d.1    5       55
c007d.1    6       60
c007d.1    7       13
```

And when I run the code shown here:

```
library(data.table)
x.out$grp <- rep(1:ceiling(nrow(x.out)/3),each=3)
output <- x.out[, if(all(V3 > 25)) c(as.character(V1[1]), 
                  V2[1], V2[3], as.list(V3)), by = grp]
```

The output looks like this:

```
      grp   V1  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1:    2    d3.1  4  6 31 55 60
```

The code checks if column 3 has 3 lines that have values over 25 back-to-back, and if it does, prints the first line of column 2 where that happens, and the last.

This works fine for the small data shown here. But when I run it on a file that has 16,000 lines, I run into the error mentioned above. Is there a way around this? I am not particularly tied down to using `data.table` but I understand it's faster than other options.

---

Here's the output of `dput(x.out)`:

```
> head(dput(x.out))

structure(list(V1 = c("c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", 
"c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1", "c007d.1"), V2 = 1:287, 
V3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 24, 33, 43, 47, 48, 48, 48, 50, 53, 63, 70, 78, 82, 
82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 84, 84, 84, 87, 88, 88, 93, 103, 138, 
158, 175, 186, 222, 319, 398, 487, 540, 554, 574, 581, 584, 
587, 588, 587, 559, 557, 557, 557, 556, 556, 556, 556, 556, 
556, 554, 554, 546, 542, 530, 478, 462, 454, 437, 412, 374, 
246, 244, 211, 54, 49, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10, 12, 21, 68, 147, 533, 588, 600, 
601, 620, 646, 666, 694, 709, 725, 729, 737, 743, 750, 784, 
805, 829, 849, 907, 929, 957, 982, 984), grp = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 
55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 
63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 
67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 
71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 
79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 
83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 
87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 96L, 96L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "grp"), row.names = c(NA, 
-287L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fdb7b006d78>)
```

Comment: this is not reproducible. It isn't clear what you are intending the `output` to look like / be

Comment: I edited the post to make my example clearer

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(x.out)` as that will help folks provide assistance.

Comment: if the same output could be generated with data.frame instead of data.table that would be great.

Comment: Please see the dput(x.out) output above

Answer (score 2):

The error message is really quite self-explanatory.

A reproducible example is what you should provide. Here is one (replacing V3 in row 7 of your example)

```
x.out <- data.table(structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
 .Label = "c007d.1", class = "factor"), 
  V2 = 1:7, V3 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 31L, 55L, 60L, 26L)), 
.Names = c("V1",  "V2", "V3"),
 class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L)))


# add your grouping column (data.table style)
x.out[, grp := rep(seq_len(ceiling(.N/3)), each = 3,length.out=.N)]
```

Your issue is that for grp=2 you have 3 rows in V3, in grp=3, you have 1, therefore when you use `as.list` (in conjunction with `c`), you create lists with differing lengths.

How do you want to fill in the missing columns for grp=3?

EDIT:

For your reproducible example, all `grp`s have rows except for grp 96..

Comment: the missing columns can just be 0's, since I only care about things that have more than 25 in V3. However, I have many files (1000's) so can it be generalized to fill in missing columns for the grps across all files?

Comment: when I add in the grouping command you suggest, I no longer get grouping by 3 lines at a time. I just get 1 grp, based on the example you provided.

Comment: It seems like I am still getting the error message when there are only 2 lines in a group that's supposed to have 3 lines.

Comment: The current error message I get is because there is a grp with 2 lines and not 3 lines.